# Powershell in Batch file: Errors and Commands not executing

Tags: powershell, batch-file, batch-processing

Below you can find the content of the two example text files I will use, `example1.txt` and `obf_example1.txt`. The latter one contains the string of `example1.txt` at the end of the file but has some obfuscated strings before.

`example1.txt`:

```
adasdkasdaksdasdkjlasdjasndjasd.
```

`obf_example1.txt`:

```
ŠxpÃÒ²Ø-Gêÿ ój"f>ïí   H€À(ø4$/+#6Ni9Pvü¶ |CF CÀ¾ý~ª-°à9ÉOÿ V[o¦.E…-Š  ƒ9Ú\žê*D´ß()^“£¹ìÅjXÑÍ¥â(¨µ×d'«P|I*èSººº&)Ø|Ì‰ òÔ®¥Ô$LÁ:9ŠLá{¶nZÒØ¨NÙÀØŒ‹0õ´Sék›áÇÉîÆbËF§BÐ„ƒöZKaÒR ²°ÅšDn?+¶()IªP›$ÇEv©¡k€[ßè¨×q-Ëk!µTóPA²—: A ?ÉEEEGÐJúÌ©ÒWµHB¡aäXû|ÓË BPÁwr„Ûi¥åÜºÈQ÷ORàSb,Šv¢D ,Žb’(2 öb¢wtKzíÄ¦#ï¯u©²Ù  aîRéš¬ëÌTbà÷¥3ÄtSGì´R$)X   Šù
'¹¨D³ÞeOK3!{·‹¦cäÐ¸NÅô:Na1žAÇ1ø8 &Fuôë %¸T¯_òMå†C"ý¤F   ™º„Iµºí4Ü¡ˆc!ì•+3 ‰‹M K@JÁ«8¢bsL†!Ù“à­šn·öMå•Œ&ýèvÀ}¨?¦hùÊò(É@Žf~5‰‘qØçþƒ‰Å²ÓÖÊJU•âNWÁ«L¼Y”$G¢ßè&§ÖÉØŒS‘WàË„°SØW Ð¨´_è%‚Å¢ø.ãÃð”#X^þ*1þ‚q85¡lÒ‚Ò>‘¸ÿ £ôQôz#ø¤ÎõÚªï|Xö%;åÍËûGú+îUƒö³‰›p    U±Ò ðtÜGÜÿ  ð,åXÿ k8È I”ÿ “½¿Ð`¨u5=SÓqyFÈ É8ôã¨ð£è6’H@lÄI10‚Ö§ÑdµÖ?t¡]D†9Zj,¥EÉºÜEq¤@,ìn—¢º‚´€bc·ú¨Lû£ÿ Ó×ÿÙ||adasdkasdaksdasdkjlasdjasndjasd.
```

When I ran the following powershell command for `example.txt` in a batch file, it works and I get the output of example.txt:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell Get-Content .\example.txt') do set _output=%%a
echo %_output%

adasdkasdaksdasdkjlasdjasndjasd
```

Good so far.

However, when I ran the above powershell command for `obf_example1.txt`, it does not work and I get the following error message:

```
'Â¹Â¨DÂ³ÃzeOK3!{Â·â?¹Â¦cÃ¤Ã?Â?Â¸Â?NÃ.Ã´:Na1Å¾AÃ╬1Ã¸8 
The command "FuÃ´Ã«Â" is either misspelled or could not be found.
The command "Ã½Ã¨vÃ?}Â¨?Â¦hÃ¹ÃSÂ?Ã²" is either misspelled or could not be found.
```

Why? Never mind I thought: As I am only interested in the last `n` characters both in `example1.txt` and `obf_example1.txt` accordingly, my idea was to extract the last `n` characters and check if I can see the output of `obf_example1.txt` then. To check if my idea works, I run the following command for `example1.txt` to get the last 4 characters as an example:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell $a=Get-Content .\example.txt; $a.substring^(0,$a.length-4^)') do set _output=%%a
echo.%_output%
```

It doesn't show me anything though. `%_output%` seems to be empty. How to fix that? And will the fixed version work for `obf_example1.txt` as well so that I get an output there instead of the above error message?

Comment: There are Ampersands and Pipes in your data.  When you echo the output, the variable value is expanded first and then the command is executed.  It sees the & and | as command arguments.

Comment: Is it really necessary for you to call powershell from cmd? I recommend sticking to one or the other.

Comment: `echo "%_output%"` should cure that - except there are quotes in the text file (then it depends on where exactly they are in relation to those poison chars whether it works or not)

Comment: @Thomas : I wasn't able to get the last `n` characters for `obf_example1.txt` in pure batch, I always got an error with the `type` command or `echo` when trying to echo the obfuscated file. That's why I mix with powershell and use Get-Content and stuff. If you can help me out doing that in pure batch, I'd highly appreciate it.

Comment: @Stephan: No, `echo "%_output%"` did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try reading the last 4 bytes, if you really are taking text characters from what is clearly not a text file. *(My guess is that it is text hidden inside a binary file, probably a graphic file)*.

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In (
 '%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -NoP^
 "$f=[IO.File]::OpenRead('C:\Users\Ferit\Desktop\obf_example1.txt');"^
 "$f.Seek(-4,[System.IO.SeekOrigin]::End)|Out-Null;$buffer=new-object Byte[] 4;"^
 "$f.Read($buffer,0,4)|Out-Null;$f.Close();"^
 "[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($buffer)"')Do @Set "_output=%%G"
@Set _output 2>NUL&&Pause
```

Don't forget to modify the text file path, *(on line `3`)*, and the three instances of `4` if you want more or less bytes. The last line is included just to show you the output, *(you would obviously replace that with your own code)*.

Comment: That helped - thank you so much! One last thing where I need your help: How can I put the last `n` bytes to a batch variable (without the string `_output`) in order to further operate in my batch?

Comment: I've already explained that the last line was included just to show you the output, you'd use, `%_output%` in your own code, wherever you like. For now, if you want, you can use `@If Defined _output Echo %_output%&Pause` as your replacement last line.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the piece of text you are after is behind the `||`.

With PowerShell you can easily get that by using

```
((Get-Content 'D:\Test\obf_example1.txt' -Raw) -split '\|\|')[-1]
```

Returns

> adasdkasdaksdasdkjlasdjasndjasd

Isn't htis what you want?

Comment: Most likely yes but I need this command to be included in a batch file. Having tried `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell (Get-Content .\obf_example.txt -Raw) -split '\|\|')[1]') do set _output=%%a` and then output it with `echo "%_output%"` it shows me the error message `"-split" cannot be processed syntactically at this point.` Could you please help me including your command in a batch file format?

Comment: Try with giving it an absolute file path to read from. The current directory for PowerShell may not be the same as for cmd. However, why use cmd to run PowerShell and not PS directly for this? If you must, enter this in the cmd: `powershell ((Get-Content 'D:\Test\obf_example1.txt' -Raw) -split '^\^|^\^|')[-1]`. It will return `adasdkasdaksdasdkjlasdjasndjasd.` P.S. you need to escape the pipe characters with `^` aswell as the backslashes in the split string.

Comment: I tried it with that but it still says `-split" cannot be processed syntactically at this point`. This is what I do: `@echo off <new line> for /f "delims=" %%a in (powershell ((Get-Content '.\obf_example1.txt' -Raw) -split '^\^|^\^|')[-1]) do set _output=%%a <new line> echo.%_output%`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me to get the "clear-text" part after `||` (from your example):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (.\obf_example1.txt) do set "_output=%%a"
set _output
echo testing last 10: %_output:~-10%
set "_output=%_output:*||=%"
set _output
echo %_output%
```

(it might not work with different encodings of the text file)

(Consider Powershell - `cmd` has a limit on line length and can easily be overwhelmed)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. Yes you are right, the `obf_example1.txt` was only an example though, it did not work for a larger example. Is there any chance to deal with a larger example? Background of my question is that I want to extract a hidden text in a jpg file with batch. The hidden text is usually at the end of the jpg file which is much larger than what I provided in my example `obf_example1.txt`.

Comment: You cannot overcome the line limit, but if you are able to insert a `CRLF` (instead of the `||`), it's a *new* line. Then my first line alone should be able to extract the wanted string ("last line"), no matter how big the file is.

Comment: Thank you Stephan for your support. I changed the `||` to `CRLF` instead. My batch file looks right now like this: `@echo off`, <new line> `for /f "delims=" %%a in (.\image.jpg) do set "_output=%%a"` <new line> `echo %_output:~-3%` --> It prints out `~-3`. Any idea why it does not show the last 3 lines instead?

Comment: That usually happens, when the variable is empty. Does it happen with my code above (without modifying or inserting it into other code) too? What does `set _output` say?